# Unexpected output when iterating through an array with a for( ... in ...) loop

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


Array.prototype.getUnique = function () {
    var o = new Object();
    var i, e;
    for (i = 0; e = this[i]; i++) {o[e] = 1};
    var a = new Array();
    for (e in o) {a.push (e)};
    return a;
}

function Perform(){
    var arr = new Array();

    arr[0] = "hello";
    arr[1] = "world";

    for(i in arr){
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="Perform()">
</body>
</html>
```

The result of above code in console is

```
hello
world
function()
```

From where does the last `function()` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for ... in` in JavaScript **DOES NOT ITERATE AN ARRAY**.  Forget your other programming languages -- this is JavaScript, the language with similar syntax that means *completely different things*.

`for ... in` iterates through all the *properties* of the object, including all propertes in its prototype chain.

Therefore, *always use hasOwnProperty* to check whether the property is defined on the object itself:

```
for (var name in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    doSomething(obj[name]);
  }
}
```

You **should not** use `for ... in` to iterate an array.  Use an index instead.

Search SO for hundreds of similar questions on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

The `function()` is coming from the `prototype` - it is the `getUnique` function.

---

To avoid this, you shouldn't be iterating through arrays with a `for .. in` loop. Use the plain old:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

In cases where you must use `for .. in` (for example, iterating through keys of an object), you should always check `hasOwnProperty()`:

```
for (var i in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}
```